# Can I call done without passing done into my real implementation?

Tags: ajax, jasmine, karma-jasmine, mockjax, jasmine2.0

I am writing some jasmine tests and using mockjax to mock out my ajax calls.
I know jasmine requires some extra work to get it to work asynchronously but i dont like my solution.

I am passing in '`done`' into my real implementation and then calling this from within the promise on my ajax request.

All the examples seem to be using setTimeouts as "simulations" which is not entirely helpful in my opinion.

Here's some code to help understand:

### Jasmine

```
    $.mockjax({
        url: "*/api/AdminBenefits",
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "post"
    });

    beforeEach(function (done)
    {
        vm.benefit.benefitName(expectedBenefitName);
        vm.addBenefit(done); <---- Dirty
    });

    //Assert
    it('should toast success', function (done)
    {
        expect(fakeToastr.successValue()).toEqual('"' + expectedBenefitName + '"' + " was added successfully.");
        done();
    });
```

### implementation

```
model.addBenefit = function(callback) <---- Dirty
{
    var value = model.benefit.benefitName();

    $.ajax({
        url: rootPath + "/api/AdminBenefit",
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "post",
        data: ko.toJSON(model.benefit)
    }).done(function(data) {
        toastr.success("\"" + value + "\"" + " was added successfully.");
        !callback || callback(); <---- Dirty
    }).fail(function() {
        !callback || callback(); <---- Dirty
    });
}
```

Am I going about this all wrong?

Just to re-iterate I want to let jasmine know when mockjax / ajax is .done() without passing in `done` from jasmine into my viewmodel.

Comment: Unfortunately this is all you can really do. The calling code (in this case your test) needs to know when the functionality is complete (ready to be tested). Using a callback is one option, but you could also implement promises and return that from your function. You still would need to resolve or reject within the code, but at least there is no argument to pass in.

Comment: Hmm yes, not sure which i prefer. It's a shame mockjax doesn't have a call back that you can hook into. I added an issue for them in case it's something they think is worth adding. https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax/issues/200

Comment: See my comment on the Github issue, but I don't think that's how you really want things to be organized for proper testing.

Answer (score 1):

I never followed this up with an answer after posting an answer in the [Github issue](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax/issues/200) you opened, but the code below is how I typically see this implemented in the tests. Note that you might also want to return some result from your source code in the `callback()`, but that is only if you want to do assertions on that result data (which may be a good idea).

Test code:

```
describe("Some functionality", function() {
    beforeEach(function ()
    {
        $.mockjax({
            url: "*/api/AdminBenefits",
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: "post"
        });
    });

    it('should toast success', function (done)
    {
        vm.benefit.benefitName(expectedBenefitName);
        vm.addBenefit(function()
        {
            expect(fakeToastr.successValue()).toEqual('"' + expectedBenefitName + '"' + " was added successfully.");
            // possibly other assertions on the result data passed in the callback...

            done(); // tell jasmine you're done with async action
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Many thanks, I have provided code to how I solved this also. Just to confirm wont this timeout in the `beforeEach`? I thought that jasmine will not go into the `it` until the `done` is resolved in the `beforeEach`.

Comment: Oops... yes. :) I've removed the `done()` in the `beforeEach()`, it is not necessary in my code.

Answer (score 0):

As jakerella was kind enough to provide an answer I decided i should also show how i solved the problem here, I have opted for the solution he provided me on GitHub and defined an onAfterComplete.

```
describe("When clicking the add benefit type button and the server is successful", function () {
    //Arrange
    var expectedBenefit;

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        vm.Reset();
        expectedBenefit = vm.setRandomBenefit();

        $.mockjax({
            url: "*/api/AddBenefitType",
            type: "post",
            onAfterComplete: function () { done(); } //<------
        });

        //Act
        vm.addCurrentBenefit();
    });

    //Assert
    it('should toast success', function (done) {
        expect(toastr.successValue()).toEqual('"' + expectedBenefit.Name + '"' + " was added successfully.");
        done();
    });
```